# Django: Can't display data from an abstract model in template

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to display data from table(Tornillos) that inherits from table (articulos. abstract table) i want to get the value from sistema to display on my template.

My views.py

```
# def tipo_medicion(request, id):
def tipo_medicion(request):
    template = 'inventario/sistema.html'
    try:
        sis = Tornillo.objects.values('sistema').distinct()
        print(sis)
    except Tornillo.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404()
    #return render(request, template, { sis:'sis', id:'id' })
    return render(request, template, { sis:'sis' })
```

My Server terminal screen:

```
[11/Jun/2018 23:55:10] "GET /sistema-medicion/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 761
<QuerySet [{'sistema': 'MM'}, {'sistema': 'STD'}]>
[11/Jun/2018 23:55:10] "GET /sistema-medicion/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 761
```

My Template:

```
{% extends 'inventario/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="tag">SISTEMA</h1>
    <ul>
      {% for s in sis %}
        <li>{{s.sistema}}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I'am struggling with an other issue i don't understand the concept yet for urlconf. currently my url for this view is static, i have tried  with  and get  an inspected value  error

My urls.py

```
app_name = 'inventario'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index' ),
    path('categorias/', views.categorias, name='categorias'),
    path('sistema-medicion/2', views.tipo_medicion, name='medicion')
    #path('sistema-medicion/<int:id>', views.tipo_medicion, name='medicion')
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have reversed the key with the value in your dictionary

```
def tipo_medicion(request):
     ...
    return render(request, template, { 'sis':sis })
```

**urls.py**

```
path('sistema-medicion/<int:pk>/', views.tipo_medicion, name='medicion')
```